# Need to count a number of programmatically created objects in separate script

Tags: unity

I have a game that creates and places a random number of "pickups" on a plane at random places.

I then have a script on the "Player" game object that uses `OnTriggerEnter` to tell when an item has been "picked up" and compares a count (the score) to the number of objects that are created:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    // Get all game objects with the Tag "Pickup"

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pickup")) {

        // Deactivate objects that are touched/collected
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);

        // add to count
        count++;

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + count;

        //TODO: fix this statement; pickupCount is always 0 here, why?

        if(count >= pickupCount){
            winText.text = "You Win!";
        }

    }

}
```

The problem I am facing is that during building this worked fine, I built the project and it outputted "You Win!" after picking up 1 "pickup", I found out this is because for some reason the value of `pickupCount` is now always 0.

`pickupCount =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pickup").Length;`

My guess is that because the Playerscript checks at `Start()` and the SpawnScript creates at `Start()` that the reason the number is always 0 is because at the time of checking there are in fact no "pickups" created. My question is then, how do I check for the total number of these pickups without doing it in an update function?

**SIDE NOTE**

I know I could just change the `OnTriggerEnter()` function to be something like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    // Get all game objects with the Tag "Pickup"

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pickup")) {

        // Deactivate objects that are touched/collected
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);

        // check number of pickups left
        pickupCount =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pickup").Length;

        // add to count to show the score
        count++;

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + count;

        if(pickupCount <= 0){
            winText.text = "You Win!";
        }

    }
}
```

But it is more a case of curiosity now more than anything. Is what I am asking even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do this with a static variable on a script attached to your pickups:

```
public class CountedPickup : MonoBehaviour {

    static int _pickupsRemaining;
    public static int PickupsRemaining { get { return _pickupsRemaining; } }

    void OnEnable() {
        _pickupsRemaining++;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        _pickupsRemaining--;
    }
}
```

Now your player script (or any other) can check `CountedPickup.PickupsRemaining == 0` to check how many are left to collect.

This will work even if this component doesn't know anything about what *kind* of pickup it is (it just represents the idea that this pickup should be included in the count, even if you mix & match different types of pickups in one level), and whether you `Instantiate()` & `Destroy()` pickups, or just toggle them on and off with `gameObject.SetActive()`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the most elegant approach to this problem, but to respond to this part of your problem:

> My guess is that because the Playerscript checks at Start() and the SpawnScript creates at Start() that the reason the number is always 0 is because at the time of checking there are in fact no "pickups" created.

Note that it's pretty easy to make some code execute once at a later time. There are multiple approaches, but the simplest is [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html).